# MATIC stuck in contract

Tags: blockchain, metamask

I have a smart contract with some Matic balance on it. I can't pull out those matic balance on the contract... what did I miss?

```
function _forwardFunds() payable public {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    treasuryAddress.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

Comment: I think I can help you if you show me the contract.
There has to be a logical fault in the code. I hope you reply to this.
~Shadow

Comment: When you say you "can't pull out those matic" what does it mean? The transaction reverts, it does nothing, something else. Can you share a transaction hash of the error?

Answer (score 0):

No need, its trapped, cant do nothing

```
function transferToTreasury(uint256 _amount) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "Only contract owner can call this function");
    token.transfer(treasuryAddress, _amount);
}

function _forwardFunds() payable public {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    treasuryAddress.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "logical fault" being that
`treasuryAddress.transfer(msg.value);` should be `treasuryAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);` (although the function does exactly what its name claims it does, it forwards funds being sent to it to the treasury address, so you're more likely just missing a separate function that does what i described above). But yeah, if the 2 functions you sent are the only ones that deal with funds, your funds are stuck, your contract can transfer out ERC20s being sent to it just fine, but not MATIC